# Extension Library Dialog Control

Tags: xpages

I would think this blog post, [by Mark Hughes](http://blog.hughesconnect.com/?p=21), would no longer be relevant in 9.0.1 FP1 SHF309 and ExtLib version 9.0.1v00_10_20141105-0922.  However, I am using the ExtLib dialog control that is 4 panels deep and the only way I can get it to display is with a Full Update.  It is always appearing outside the form tags as shown in this screenshot, [image], and even if I create a CSS class to set the position to absolute and z-index to 950 it won't show with a partial refresh.

The dialog is actually within a custom control, ccSettleAtmConfirmation, towards the bottom of the 'settlementPanel'.  I have tried to do a partial refresh of each of the four panels and another partial refresh in the onComplete with no luck.  To make things a bit easier this is the SSJS in the button:

```
try {
    sessionScope.infoMsg = "";
//Did you confirm settlement amount?
    var now:Date = @Now();
    var nineAM:Date = @Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+1, now.getDate(), 9, 0, 0) //Runs on the server, which is always in VA (ET)
    if(viewScope.settlementOptions == "Initiate Settlement"){
        if(now.UTC() <= nineAM.UTC()){
            sessionScope.infoMsg = "You cannot initiate settlement of " + atmBean.atmID + " as the current time is prior or equal to 0900 ET";
        } else { //SRD FR103072, FR79121
            var sttlDialog = getComponent("sttlDlg");
            sttlDialog.show();
        }
    }
} catch (e) {
    logInfo("Settlement: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    sessionScope.infoMsg = "Error trying to open confirmation prompt.  Please try again.";
}
```

Code for the 4 layers of panels which contain the button which shows the dialog.

```
<xp:panel id="panel1">
<xp:panel id="panel2">
<xp:panel id="panel3">
                <xp:panel id="settlementPanel">
                    <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.operation == "Settlement"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
                    <xp:table style="width:100%">
                        <xp:tr>
                            <xp:td style="width:3%" />
                            <xp:td style="width:81.0%">
                                <xp:table style="width:100%">
                                    <xp:tr>
                                        <xp:td style="width:40%" styleClass="home-table-cell">
                                            <xp:label value="Today's Settlement Amount:"
                                                styleClass="home-label" id="label9" />
                                        </xp:td>
                                        <xp:td>
                                            <xp:inputText id="inputText6" style="font-size:12pt;width:8em"
                                                value="#{atmBean.atmTodaySettlementAmt}" styleClass="non-editable clear-on-cancel">
                                            </xp:inputText>
                                            <!--                                    <xp:message id="message1"></xp:message>-->

                                        </xp:td>
                                    </xp:tr>
                                    <xp:tr>
                                        <xp:td styleClass="home-table-cell" style="width:40%">
                                            <xp:label value="Options for Settlement:"
                                                styleClass="home-label" id="label10" />
                                        </xp:td>
                                        <xp:td style="width:60%">
                                            <script>
                                                $(function()
                                                {$('input.currency-mask').numericInput();});
                                            </script>
                                            <xp:comboBox id="comboBox1"
                                                style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:12pt;width:16em"
                                                styleClass="editable clear-on-cancel" value="#{viewScope.settlementOptions}"
                                                defaultValue="--">
                                                <xp:selectItems id="selectItems2">
                                                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://keywordBean.getReportCombobox();
if(atmBean.atmStatus == "IN PROGRESS") {
    //viewScope.put('settlementOptions',@Trim(keywordBean.getVector("SettlementInProgressAtmStatus")));
    return @Trim(keywordBean.getVector("SettlementInProgressAtmStatus"));
} else if(atmBean.atmStatus == "OPEN" || atmBean.atmStatus == "CLOSED" || atmBean.atmStatus == "WOUNDED") {
    //viewScope.put('settlementOptions',@Trim(keywordBean.getVector("SettlementOpenClosedWoundedAtmStatus")));
    return @Trim(keywordBean.getVector("SettlementOpenClosedWoundedAtmStatus"));
} else if(atmBean.atmStatus == "MASS CLOSEOUT IN PROGRESS") {
    //viewScope.put('settlementOptions',@Trim(keywordBean.getVector("SettlementMassCloseoutInProgressAtmStatus")));
    return @Trim(keywordBean.getVector("SettlementMassCloseoutInProgressAtmStatus"));
}
return @Trim(keywordBean.getVector("SettlementOptions"));}]]></xp:this.value>
                                                </xp:selectItems>
                                                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                                                    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="settlementPanel">
                                                    <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:infoMessagePanel}",{onStart:null,onError:null,onComplete:null});]]></xp:this.onComplete>
                                                </xp:eventHandler>
                                            </xp:comboBox>
                                        </xp:td>
                                    </xp:tr>
                                    <xp:tr>
                                        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:var currDt:java.util.Date = new java.util.Date();
var busDt:java.util.Date = atmBean.atmBusinessDate;

if(atmBean.atmStatus == "OPEN" || atmBean.atmStatus == "CLOSED" || atmBean.atmStatus == "WOUNDED") {
    if(viewScope.get('settlementOptions') == "Initiate Settlement") {
        if(@Date(currDt).equals(@Date(busDt))) {
            return true;
        } else {
//          sessionScope.infoMsg = "The Settlement function cannot be performed on this ATM because " + atmBean.atmID + "'s Business Date is greater than the current date";
//          return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}}]]></xp:this.rendered>
                                        <xp:td
                                            styleClass="home-table-cell" style="width:40%">
                                            <xp:label
                                                value="Is the Settlement Amount correct?"
                                                styleClass="home-label" id="label11" />
                                        </xp:td>
                                        <xp:td style="width:60%">
                                            <xp:radioGroup
                                                id="radioGroup2" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:12pt"
                                                value="#{viewScope.settlementCorrectYN}"
                                                styleClass="clear-on-cancel">
                                                <xp:selectItem
                                                    itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Y" id="selectItem6" />
                                                <xp:selectItem
                                                    itemLabel="No" itemValue="N" id="selectItem7" />
                                                <xp:eventHandler
                                                    event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
                                                    refreshId="settlementPanel" id="eventHandler4">
                                                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[$(".amtRec").val(""); //works in IE
//$(".amtRec").text(""); //works in Chrome ???
//this is needed because of the way that the jQuery plugin works]]></xp:this.script>
                                                    <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[$(".amtRec").numericInput();]]></xp:this.onComplete>
                                                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:atmBean.atmAmountReceived = null;
/*
if(viewScope.settlementCorrectYN == "N"){
    atmBean.atmAmountReceived = null;
}
*/}]]></xp:this.action>
                                                </xp:eventHandler>

                                            </xp:radioGroup>
                                        </xp:td>
                                    </xp:tr>
                                    <xp:tr>
                                        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(viewScope.get('settlementCorrectYN') == 'N') {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}}]]></xp:this.rendered>
                                        <xp:td styleClass="home-table-cell" style="width:40%">

                                            <xp:label value="Amount Received:" styleClass="home-label"
                                                id="label12" />
                                        </xp:td>
                                        <xp:td style="width:60%">

                                            <xp:inputText id="atmAmtRcvd" value="#{atmBean.atmAmountReceived}"
                                                style="font-size:12pt">
                                                <xp:this.disabled><![CDATA[#{javascript:/*
if(viewScope.settlementCorrectYN == "N"){
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
*/}]]></xp:this.disabled>
                                                <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(viewScope.settlementCorrectYN == "N"){
    return "editable currency-mask clear-on-cancel amtRec";
} else {
    return "unavailable clear-on-cancel";
}}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
                                                <xp:eventHandler event="onkeypress" submit="false">
                                                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[/*
48 - 57: 0-9
8: backspace
9: horizontal tab
35: end
36: home
37: left arrow
39: right arrow
46: delete
var keyCode = event.keyCode;
if((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) ||keyCode == 8 || keyCode == 9 || keyCode == 35 || keyCode == 36 || keyCode == 37 || keyCode == 39 || keyCode == 46){
    event.returnValue = true;
}else{
    event.returnValue = false;
}
*/]]></xp:this.script>
                                                </xp:eventHandler>
                                                <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
                                                    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="settlementPanel">

                                                </xp:eventHandler>
                                            </xp:inputText>
                                            <!--                                    <xp:message id="message1"></xp:message>-->

                                        </xp:td>
                                    </xp:tr>
                                    <xp:tr>
                                        <xp:td style="width:40%" styleClass="home-table-cell">
                                            <xp:label value="Comments (Optional):" styleClass="home-label"
                                                id="label8" />
                                        </xp:td>
                                        <xp:td style="width:60%;padding-top:1.0em">
                                            <xp:inputTextarea id="inputTextarea3" style="height:4em;width:25em"
                                                value="#{atmBean.commentsSettle}" styleClass="clear-on-cancel" />

                                        </xp:td>
                                    </xp:tr>
                                    <xp:tr>
                                        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(atmBean.atmStatus == "WOUNDED"){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}}]]></xp:this.rendered>
                                        <xp:td styleClass="home-table-cell" style="width:40%">
                                            <xp:label value="Wounded Updates:" styleClass="home-label"
                                                id="label13" />
                                        </xp:td>
                                        <xp:td style="width:60%">
                                            <xp:inputTextarea id="inputTextarea4" style="height:4em;width:25em"
                                                value="#{atmBean.woundedUpdates}" styleClass="clear-on-cancel" />

                                        </xp:td>
                                    </xp:tr>
                                    <xp:tr>
                                        <xp:td colspan="2" styleClass="home-table-cell" align="center"
                                            valign="middle">
                                            **<xp:button
                                                value="Settle ATM" id="button14" style="font-size:11pt">
                                                <xp:this.disabled><![CDATA[#{javascript:var hol:java.util.ArrayList = keywordBean.getString("holidaysBlast");
var currDt:Date = @Today();
var sdf:java.text.SimpleDateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

if(@Contains(hol,sdf.format(currDt))) {
    return true;
} else if(viewScope.settlementOptions == "--" || viewScope.settlementOptions == null) {
    return true;
} else if(viewScope.settlementOptions == "Initiate Settlement") {
    if(viewScope.settlementCorrectYN == null || (viewScope.settlementCorrectYN == "N" & getComponent("atmAmtRcvd").getValue() == null)) {
        return true;
    }
} else if(viewScope.settlementOptions == "No Settlement Process Allowed") {
    return true;
}
return false}]]></xp:this.disabled>
                                                <xp:eventHandler
                                                    event="onclick" submit="true" id="eventHandler5"
                                                    refreshMode="complete">
                                                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[//XSP.openDialog("#{id:sttlDlg}");
/*
var deferred = atmRPC.settleAtmConfirmation();
deferred.addCallback(function(result){
    if (result == "false") {
        XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:infoMessagePanel}",{onStart:null,onError:null,onComplete:null});
    } else if(result == "true"){
        XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:infoMessagePanel}",{onStart:null,onError:null,onComplete:null});
        XSP.openDialog("#{id:sttlDlg}");
    }
})
*/]]></xp:this.script>
                                                    <!--
                                                        <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:infoMessagePanel}",
                                                        { onStart:null, onError:null, onComplete:
                                                        null});]]></xp:this.onComplete>
                                                    -->
                                                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:try {
    sessionScope.infoMsg = "";
//Did you confirm settlement amount?
    var now:Date = @Now();
    var nineAM:Date = @Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+1, now.getDate(), 9, 0, 0) //Runs on the server, which is always in VA (ET)
    if(viewScope.settlementOptions == "Initiate Settlement"){
        if(now.UTC() <= nineAM.UTC()){
            sessionScope.infoMsg = "You cannot initiate settlement of " + atmBean.atmID + " as the current time is prior or equal to 0900 ET";
        } else { //SRD FR103072, FR79121
            var sttlDialog = getComponent("sttlDlg");
            sttlDialog.show();
        }
    }
} catch (e) {
    logInfo("Settlement: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    sessionScope.infoMsg = "Error trying to open confirmation prompt.  Please try again.";
}}]]></xp:this.action>
                                                    <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:infoMessagePanel}",{onStart:null,onError:null,onComplete:null});]]></xp:this.onComplete>
                                                </xp:eventHandler>
                                            </xp:button>**

                                            <xp:button value="Cancel" id="button11" style="font-size:11pt">
                                                <xp:eventHandler
                                                    event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
                                                    refreshId="fullPage" id="eventHandler7" immediate="false"
                                                    save="false">


                                                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript://updates may need to be made in the 'Yes' and 'No' button of the 'sttlDlg'
//id
atmBean.clearATMStatus();
atmBean.atmID = null;
atmBean.atmTodaySettlementAmt = null;
atmBean.atmAmountReceived = null;
atmBean.commentsSettle = null;
atmBean.woundedUpdates = null;
sessionScope.put('atmID',null);
viewScope.put('operation',null);
viewScope.put('settlementOptions',null);
viewScope.put('settlementCorrectYN',null);
viewScope.put('javaErrCode',null);
viewScope.put('javaErrMsg',null);
sessionScope.put('infoMsg', null)}]]></xp:this.action>

                                                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[$(".clear-on-cancel").val("");
//this is needed because of the way that the jQuery plugin works]]></xp:this.script>
                                                    <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:infoMessagePanel}",{onStart:null,onError:null,onComplete:null});]]></xp:this.onComplete>
                                                </xp:eventHandler>
                                            </xp:button>
                                        </xp:td>
                                    </xp:tr>
                                    **<xp:tr>
                                        <xp:td colspan="2">
                                            <xc:ccSettleAtmConfirmation id="sttlAtmConfirm"></xc:ccSettleAtmConfirmation>
                                        </xp:td>
                                    </xp:tr>**
                                </xp:table>
                            </xp:td>
                            <xp:td style="width:25%" />
                        </xp:tr>
                    </xp:table>
                </xp:panel>
</xp:panel>
</xp:panel>
</xp:panel>
```

Comment: Please post code, including how you're trying to show the dialog. It's correct behaviour that a dialog gets moved outside the Form tag. A Partial refresh won't display it - there are CSJS or SSJS methods to do so. Also include details of where on your XPage the Dialog Custom Control is.

Answer (score 0):

No problem here opening  xe:dialog id="dialog1" via ssjs with a partial update of a panel containing my xe:dialog ...

```
    <xp:button value="Open dialog" id="button1">
           <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
              refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelAll">
              <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("dialog1").show();}]]></xp:this.action>
           </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
```

Comment: What could be the issue then if it does work with Full Update, but not partial update to look at?  I had tried with the dojoParseOnLoad set to true without success

Comment: Show us the Xsp source code for the dialog and the link or button that is coded to open the dialog.

Comment: The code is already included.  I just tried to make it bold, but I guess when you show as a code block it won't bold.

Comment: Try moving ccSettleAtmConfirmation outside of the four nested panels and their rendered condition.